# File not found but the file is already downloaded

Tags: python, image, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, file-not-found

I'm new to Python and I'm learning about Tkinter. I was trying to display an image:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

img= ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("flower.gif"))
lab = Canvas(image=img)
lab.pack()

mainloop()
```

But somehow it shows an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'flower.gif'
```

I already checked the name and the type of the file, and I'm sure that both of them are correct. Please help?

Comment: where is `flower.gif` in relation to your python script? If its not in the same folder youll have to provide the full/relative path

Comment: Is `flower.gif` in the _current working directory_? That's often not the same directory that your script is in.

Comment: where can I check if it's in the current working directory? If it's not in the current working directory, how can I change that?

Comment: Even the path issue is fixed, your code still has other issues.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer to it, just in case there is anyone who has the same problem as me:

```
m=Tk()

img= ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("C:/Users/VAIO/Downloads/flower.gif"))
lab = Label(image=img)
lab.pack()

mainloop()
```